# I want to apply a view transition with animation

Tags: ipad

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
CGFloat xpos = responseView.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat ypos = responseView.frame.origin.y; 
[UIView transitionWithView:responseView duration:1      options:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve animations:^{ responseView.frame = CGRectMake(xpos,ypos,720,700);
    [responseView.superview bringSubviewToFront:responseView];
    [responseView.superview addSubview:responseView];
}
                completion: ^(BOOL finished)  {NSLog(@"DONE");}];   
  }
```

I want to apply a view transition with animation.I tried the code below.The code is working fine ,Now I need to change the type of the animation in a attractive manner.Please give me a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

`UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve` is not a valid animation option (though it may still work because enums are just integers after all).

For the transition style, you have the following options:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
```

You'll have to decide for yourself which looks best.